# Merging columns in a join of two tables

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have the following tables in a Hive database:

```
table1:
id  t     X
1   1     a
1   4     a
2   5     a
3   10    a

table2:
id   t    Y
1    3    b
2    6    b
2    8    b
3    15   b
```

And I would like to merge them to have a table like:

```
id   t    Z
1    1    a
1    3    b
1    4    a
2    5    a
2    6    b
2    8    b
3    10   a
3    15   b
```

Basically what I want to do is :

1. a join on the column `id` (that part is easy)
2. merge the columns `table1.t` and `table2.t` into a new column `t`
3. have the variable `Z` that is equal to `table1.X` if the corresponding `t` comes from `table1.t`, and `table2.Y` if it comes from `table2.t`
4. order the table by `id` and then by `t` (that shouldn't be too hard)

I have no idea on how to do the parts 2 and 3. I tried with an outer join on 
    `table1.id = table2.id and table1.t = table2.t`, but it doesn't merge the two columns `t`.

Any pointer would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE table3 as SELECT * FROM (SELECT id,t,X as Z FROM t3_1 UNION ALL SELECT id,t,Y as Z FROM t3_2) u1 order by id,t;
```

Although not always required, using a subquery for the union'd queries help to organize, plus you can then reference the fields from the union (e.g. `u1.id` ) in other parts of the query.

You'll need the alias on the 3rd column to make the schemas match. If the source table name was not already a column, you could do something like this:

```
select * from (select id,t,'a' from t3_1 UNION ALL select id,t,'b' from t3_2) u1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. It will insert in table 3, all the values from the other 2 tables

INSERT INTO table3 ( t, Z )
SELECT t, X
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT t, Y
FROM table2

Comment: Thanks for that but I don't have the table table3 yet. So I want to do create table3 and the command: create table table3 as select t, X from table1 UNION ALL select t,Y from table2; is not working (mismatched input 'UNION')